# Build java native from specific files using maven

Tags: maven, java-native-interface

I'm working on a maven project. some specific java files in my project relies on native code.

I compile the native code and produce .so file before building the Maven project.
I want Maven to produce the JNI header files from specific java files in my project, compile the native code against the native lib I already compiled before and pack the jars with it.

The rest of the project java/scala files are not rely on any native code but they has a dependency in classes from the java files that use the native code.

I thought about two options:
Define two modules, one will be responsible for compiling the native code and packing the jars from the relevant files. The second module will have a dependency in the first module.

Define only one pom file that do it all at once.

Although first option looks like a better approach because new projects in the future can use the native lib easily this way I was advised to do it with just one pom.xml file.

Is it possible? how I config maven to produce JNI header files and pack native code from specific files in my project?